# Redondear suma de números decimales en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Quisiera su ayuda con un proyecto de `Android Studio`, soy principiante y estoy haciendo la aplicación de una calculadora básica pero al momento de hacerlo con números decimales, en ciertas ocasiones no es tan exacto. Por ejemplo al sumar **2.3569+5.2545=7.6113997**, me da ese resultado en vez de dar solo **7.6114**, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que sea lo más exacto posible? 
Aquí abajo les dejo el código fuente que estoy usando:

```
package com.example.calculadora1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et1, et2;
private TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_número1);
    et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_número2);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_resultado);
}

//Este método realiza la suma
public void Sumar(View view){
    String valor1 = et1.getText().toString();
    String valor2 = et2.getText().toString();

    float núm1 = Float.parseFloat(valor1);
    float núm2 = Float.parseFloat(valor2);

    float suma = núm1 + núm2;

    String resultado = String.valueOf(suma);
    tv1.setText(resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la libreria de java Math, la cual posee un metodo llamado round

```
Math.round(3.2); // = 3 (int)
```

por otro lado si lo que quieres es limitar el numero de decimales puedes usar DecimalFormat (esto no significa que se modificaran el numero de decimales, solo tiene una presentacion con n numero de decimales despues del punto)

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");// el numero de ceros despues del entero
format.format(/*double,object,long*/); // > retorna string
```

saludos y buena energia, como otro comentario anterior recomiendo igualmente usar double, asi evitas perder datos y si lo necesitas para despues (una respuesta redondeada) presentas el resultado del round.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tendrias que utilizar la funcion Round de java esta te redondea los valores dependiendo lo que tengas.

```
    double pi = 3.14158;
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(pi);
    MathContext m = new MathContext(5);
    System.out.println(""+b1.round(m));
    // El output de java es 3.1416 unicamente no tienes que poner el sout para android
```

Pero recuerda que es mejor que utilices valores double ya que la mayoria de funciones necesitan valores double para que evites parseos de datos